# MySql. Помоги Чайнику

Tags: php, mysql, запрос

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT `category` 
      FROM `publication` 
      WHERE `publication`.`category` = 2 
      LIMIT 0,50) AS D1
   , (SELECT `category`
      FROM `publication` 
      WHERE `publication`.`category` = 1 
      LIMIT 0,50) AS D2
```

в переменную прихдят лишь

```
` WHERE `publication`.`category` = 1`
```

т.е. только D2. как обьединить D1 и D2?

[image: скнриншот]

[image: скриншот 2]

[image: скриншот 3]

вот видете два поля приходит. Одна с категорией 1 вторая категорией 2. Как сделать чтобы это было в одном поле. Вобще там кроме категорий будет много полей

Comment: `select .. union .. select .. union .. select`

Comment: @Lexx918 не понял. Пробовал в конец добавлять UNION ALL

Comment: разве я в комментарии писал юнион в конце? надо между селектами. и тогда результат одного будет идти следом за другим. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: *в переменную прихдят лишь* В какую переменную??? у тебя в итоге должен прийти набор записей, из 0..2500 записей, содержащих по 2 поля. Это явно больше, чем одна переменная...

Comment: @Lexx918 это не то. Мне нужно чтобы на начала например 50 категорий 1  а затем 2. А это возращает только две цифры 1 , 2

Comment: @Akina о ты кажеться в теме. Вот приходит два поля записей. Одна с первой категорией вторая с второй. Как сделать чтобы это все было в одном поле.

Comment: "У тебя два числа. Как сделать чтобы это все было в одном числе?" Дурь вопроса - ощущаешь? *это возращает только две цифры 1 , 2* А ты что ожидаешь? всё в точном соответствии с текстом запроса.

Comment: Попробуй поставить разные алиасы. Может у тебя где-то category перетираются в ассоциативном фетче

Comment: @Akina попробуйте посмотреть заново со скринам

Comment: @user8978194 Ну посмотрел. Единственное, что тут для меня неизвестного - это количество записей (48 штук). Всё остальное я знал до того, как увидел скрин. Повторю - **в точном соответствии с текстом запроса**.

Comment: @vp_arth как это сделать?

Comment: Меня сбил с толку тег php, не обращайте внимания. Опишите какой в точности resultset вы планируете получить?

Comment: @vp_arth такое же как на скрине но только чтобы на начала шла первая категория а потом вторая в одном поле.

Comment: что значит в одном поле? вы хотите их в строку сконкатенировать?

Comment: @vp_arth cмотрите когда я делаю запрос на пхп и получаю в переменную я получаю лишь D2. Как получить обе.

Comment: привидите пример ващего php кода и сформулируйте вопрос так, что бы можно было однозначно на него ответить. Так же добавьте ожидаемый результат

Answer (score 0):

Если я что-нибудь понял, простейший способ - UNION:

```
(SELECT 1 FROM `publication` WHERE `category` = 1 LIMIT 50)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 2 FROM `publication` WHERE `category` = 2 LIMIT 50)
```

---

Второй вариант задачи:

> Попробуй поставить разные алиасы. Может у тебя где-то category перетираются в ассоциативном фетче

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT `category` d1
      FROM `publication` 
      WHERE `publication`.`category` = 2 
      LIMIT 0,50) AS D1
   , (SELECT `category` d2
      FROM `publication` 
      WHERE `publication`.`category` = 1 
      LIMIT 0,50) AS D2
```

Comment: все что я получаю при таком запросе это respone[0][`category`] = 2 , respone[0][`category`] = 1;;

Comment: откуда взялся этот ваш respone? Не вижу его в вопросе

Comment: response это массив в который приходит ответ уже в программе

Comment: Существует 1001 способ данным попасть в этот массив, добавьте код в вопрос

Comment: при твоем варианте приходит скриншот 2. Взгляни на вопрос я добавил

Comment: Потому что без union all дубликаты не выводятся. Пробуй второй вариант с алиасами. И очень прошу, уточни вопрос, чтобы без хрустального шара было понятно чего тебе надо.

Comment: третий скрин ответ на запрос который нужен

Comment: т.е. union all делает почти то, что нужно?

Comment: @user8978194 здесь вам дали правильный ответ исходя из вашего вопроса

Comment: @vp_arth cмотри в зопросе который указан в вопросе есть две производный таблицы (не знаю как точно называеться) это D1 и D2. D1 имеет все публикации с категорией 1, D2 иммет публикации с категорией 2. Так вот можно ли как то их слить в одну например D3 таблицу чтобы одинаковые не терялись

Answer (score 0):

Попытка решить в общем виде:

```
select category
from 
(
   select p.category,
      (@num:=if(@group=category, @num+1, if(@group:=category, 1, 1))) row_number 
  from publication
  CROSS JOIN (select @num:=0, @group:=null) c
  order by category
) as x 
where x.row_number <= 50;
```

Лимитирование осуществлено раздельно для каждой категории(@group) с помощью переменной-счётчика(@num).

[Демонстрация](http://rextester.com/FGK56317)